# C# help, can't get list of names from 4 loops

Tags: c#, list, loops

Im trying to learn the 4 types of loops, for, foreach, while and do. I've made this code so far:

Loops.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoopFrame
{
    class Loops
    {
        // attribute (not property)
        private List<string> names;

        // constructor
        public Loops()
        {
            // initilize
            names = new List<string>();

            //insert values
            names.Add("Peter");
            names.Add("Susanne");
            names.Add("Steen");
            names.Add("Mohammed");
            names.Add("Poul");
            names.Add("Ebbe");
            names.Add("Henrik");
            names.Add("Per");
            names.Add("Anders");
            names.Add("Lars");
            names.Add("Vibeke");
            names.Add("Mogens");
            names.Add("Michael");
        }

        //
        // 4 loop methods
        //
        // all should print out the whole list 'names'
        //

        public void WhileLoop()
        {
            int x = 0;

            while (x < names.Count)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(names[++x]);
            }
        }

        public void DoWhileLoop()
        {
            int x = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(names[++x]);
                x++;
            } while (x < names.Count);
        }

        public void ForLoop()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 0; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(names[++x]);          
            }
        }

        public void ForeachLoop()
        {
            int[] names = new int[] { 0 };
            foreach (int element in names)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace LoopFrame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Loops loops = new Loops();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is some faults, but the program can currently compile, but it just makes a black screen.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried invoking one of your methods after creating the `Loop` object?

Comment: what about debugging to see what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands, you're constructing the `Loops` instance, but you've not called any methods.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Loops loops = new Loops();
    loops.WhileLoop();
    loops.DoWhileLoop();
    loops.ForLoop();
    loops.ForeachLoop();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You may want to read up on [Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

As an aside, you can populate your list with much less code:

```
names = new List<string> { "Peter", "Suzanne", "Steen" ... };
```

As another aside, in two of your loop methods, you're incrementing the index variable twice per iteration, which should only print out every other element.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling any method that should print the list content.

Add:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Loops loops = new Loops();

    //Call methods
    loops.WhileLoop();
    loops.DoWhileLoop();
    //...


    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach will not work. As you declared a new names as int[]. To make your foreach workable with declared list. You should use

`foreach(string s in names)
{
Console.WriteLine("Name is : "+s);
}`